# MS Visual Studio 2015: При смене конфигурации решения хедер файлы становятся недоступны

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Текущая конфигурация решения Debug x86. Проект компилируется успешно, без ошибок.

Меняю конфигурацию на Release x86. Сразу в коде исходников помечаются красным все #include директивы. При компиляции соответствующие ошибки.

Возможно, где-то нужно пути прописать для Release ? Никак не могу найти.